# Adding Foreign Keys to Composite Primary Key, referencing 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have a composite primary key

`PRIMARY KEY (alpha, beta)`

I want to add foreign keys to primary keys `alpha` and `beta`

I tried:

```
-- ADD FOREIGN KEY (alpha) REFERENCES green(alpha);
-- ADD FOREIGN KEY (beta) REFERENCES blue(beta);
```

This didn't work. I then tried:

```
ADD FOREIGN KEY (alpha, beta) REFERENCES green(alpha), blue(beta);
```

And this didn't work either. I can't find any examples online of adding different foreign keys to the composite primary key. Any tips would be welcome.

Comment: Pretty sure your syntax is off: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: More details, the rest of the 1064 message points at the exact place in question.  If it says "near ''", then is is probably unbalanced parens, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had UNSIGNED on the referencing table but not on the referenced. That caused the issue it seems.